# DROP FOREIGN KEY

Tags: mysql

I didn't give any name to my foreign key in MYSQL. But now I need to drop it. Can anyone help me ??

Answer (score 0):

Use below to find your constraint's name:

```
select 
    table_name,
    column_name,
    constraint_name,
    referenced_table_name,
    referenced_column_name
from information_schema.key_column_usage
where table_name = 'Your_table';
```

and then use below statement to drop it:

```
alter table your_table drop foreign key <foreign_key_constraint_name>;
```

Comment: Isn't `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` enough to see the foreign key name?

Comment: There are almost always multiple ways available to do the sam thing. I just picked one of them. Plus I'd prefer an actual query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
constraint_name
FROM
 information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE
constraint_schema = 'Blog' AND table_name = 'posts';


ALTER TABLE posts DROP Foreign Key keyname;
```